# Flutter ios error: ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant: Use of undeclared identifier 'Sounds'

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I have a Flutter app that users the `sounds` package. My app was working pretty well in both iOS and Android, but there were some errors due to the interaction between the `sounds` package `audio_service` package on Android (before I had tested iOS), so I decided to fork `sounds` to remove some pieces of the Android code to fix the error. The app then started to work well fine in Android, so I tried to test on iOS, but keep getting this error.

I don't know much about iOS development, so I'm at a loss of where to even look to solve this problem. I didn't make any changes to the code in the plugin in `ios` folder, and don't think I removed anything from `lib` that should affect this (though I'm not sure how to be sure).

Does anyone know what I need to look at to find the issue and solve this?

Here is my full `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` file:

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<audio_service/AudioServicePlugin.h>)
#import <audio_service/AudioServicePlugin.h>
#else
@import audio_service;
#endif

#if __has_include(<audio_session/AudioSessionPlugin.h>)
#import <audio_session/AudioSessionPlugin.h>
#else
@import audio_session;
#endif

#if __has_include(<audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.h>)
#import <audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.h>
#else
@import audioplayers;
#endif

#if __has_include(<cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>)
#import <cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>
#else
@import cloud_firestore;
#endif

#if __has_include(<cloud_functions/FLTFirebaseFunctionsPlugin.h>)
#import <cloud_functions/FLTFirebaseFunctionsPlugin.h>
#else
@import cloud_functions;
#endif

#if __has_include(<device_info/FLTDeviceInfoPlugin.h>)
#import <device_info/FLTDeviceInfoPlugin.h>
#else
@import device_info;
#endif

#if __has_include(<file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h>)
#import <file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h>
#else
@import file_picker;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_auth/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_auth/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_auth;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_core;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_database/FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_database/FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_database;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_messaging/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_messaging/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_messaging;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_storage/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_storage/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_storage;
#endif

#if __has_include(<flutter_isolate/FlutterIsolatePlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_isolate/FlutterIsolatePlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_isolate;
#endif

#if __has_include(<google_sign_in/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.h>)
#import <google_sign_in/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.h>
#else
@import google_sign_in;
#endif

#if __has_include(<image_cropper/FLTImageCropperPlugin.h>)
#import <image_cropper/FLTImageCropperPlugin.h>
#else
@import image_cropper;
#endif

#if __has_include(<image_picker/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>)
#import <image_picker/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>
#else
@import image_picker;
#endif

#if __has_include(<launch_review/LaunchReviewPlugin.h>)
#import <launch_review/LaunchReviewPlugin.h>
#else
@import launch_review;
#endif

#if __has_include(<package_info/FLTPackageInfoPlugin.h>)
#import <package_info/FLTPackageInfoPlugin.h>
#else
@import package_info;
#endif

#if __has_include(<path_provider/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h>)
#import <path_provider/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h>
#else
@import path_provider;
#endif

#if __has_include(<permission_handler/PermissionHandlerPlugin.h>)
#import <permission_handler/PermissionHandlerPlugin.h>
#else
@import permission_handler;
#endif

#if __has_include(<sounds/Sounds.h>)
#import <sounds/Sounds.h>
#else
@import sounds;
#endif

#if __has_include(<sqflite/SqflitePlugin.h>)
#import <sqflite/SqflitePlugin.h>
#else
@import sqflite;
#endif

#if __has_include(<url_launcher/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h>)
#import <url_launcher/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h>
#else
@import url_launcher;
#endif

#if __has_include(<wakelock/WakelockPlugin.h>)
#import <wakelock/WakelockPlugin.h>
#else
@import wakelock;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [AudioServicePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"AudioServicePlugin"]];
  [AudioSessionPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"AudioSessionPlugin"]];
  [AudioplayersPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"AudioplayersPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseFunctionsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseFunctionsPlugin"]];
  [FLTDeviceInfoPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTDeviceInfoPlugin"]];
  [FilePickerPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FilePickerPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseCorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseCorePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin"]];
  [FlutterIsolatePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterIsolatePlugin"]];
  [FLTGoogleSignInPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTGoogleSignInPlugin"]];
  [FLTImageCropperPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTImageCropperPlugin"]];
  [FLTImagePickerPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTImagePickerPlugin"]];
  [LaunchReviewPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"LaunchReviewPlugin"]];
  [FLTPackageInfoPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTPackageInfoPlugin"]];
  [FLTPathProviderPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTPathProviderPlugin"]];
  [PermissionHandlerPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"PermissionHandlerPlugin"]];
  [Sounds registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"Sounds"]];
  [SqflitePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"SqflitePlugin"]];
  [FLTURLLauncherPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTURLLauncherPlugin"]];
  [WakelockPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"WakelockPlugin"]];
}

@end
```